# erro pods QBImagePickerController

Tags: genexus

Estoy actualizando mi base de conocimiento a la versión Genexus 18 (antes usaba la versión Genexus 17 Upgrade 9) y tengo un problema en el build donde me da el error:

**error: Firmar para "QBImagePickerController-QBImagePicker" requiere un equipo de desarrollo. Seleccione un equipo de desarrollo en el editor Firma y capacidades. (en el destino 'QBImagePickerController-QBImagePicker' del proyecto 'Pods')**
Sin embargo, en la configuración de genexus, el ID del equipo de desarrollo ya está configurado. en el proyecto mac, los pods QBImagePickerController-QBImagePicker no están firmados, el resto está firmado.
como solucionar esto en genexus? (porque en mac funciona si pones la firma correcta en los pods)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Como estas?

Abri el proyecto .xcworkspace en tu mac y en "Signing & Capabilities" asignale el team id, tal como dice el error. Con eso deberias poder salir adelante.

Comment: 0



si, en mac puedo hacerlo, pero cada vez que el proyecto es construido por genexus tengo que repetir el proceso en mac.